# UIWebView acts different from Safari on Amazon.com

Tags: uiwebview, hover

I'm developing a web browser for iOS & i noticed UIWebView behaves different than safari in some cases. One I i couldn't figure out is Amazon's site.

When i click "Sign In" on the top right menu bar on the iPad safari, it opens a popup in which i can chose "You Account" to load the login page.

But when i try it on a plain UIWebView, it doesn't show the popup. I suspect it has something to do with the hover effect but was not able to solve it.

Any ideas?

Gil

[image]

expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that UIWebView has problems with executing some of the JavaScript on the amazon's website.[1](http://undefinedvalue.com/2011/07/25/beware-lure-ios-uiwebview)

Maybe using alternatives, like Three20's TTWebController or CIALBrowser could help?